# Cannot uninstall pycrypto: cannot find pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I was installing pycrypto, and was careless and installed the win32 version instead. Unfortunately, when I go to uninstall it, it cannot find the file specified (full error below). Thanks for any help.

```
Uninstalling pycrypto-2.6:
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
Successfully uninstalled pycrypto-2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 233, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 252, in main
pip_version_check(session)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\outdated.py", line 102, in 
pip_version_check
installed_version = get_installed_version("pip")
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 838, in 
get_installed_version
working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", 
line 644, in __init__
self.add_entry(entry)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", 
line 700, in add_entry
for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", 
line 1949, in find_eggs_in_zip
if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", 
line 1463, in has_metadata
return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", 
line 1823, in _has
return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", 
line 1703, in zipinfo
return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", 
line 1643, in load
mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg'
```

Comment: Hello, this is a software dev site, so your question might be best in other support forums.  However, you should identify what OS you are running, how you installed the python package, and what you ran to uninstall it.  Likely Pip, but this would help.

Answer (score 0):

The key parts of the output are:

```
Uninstalling pycrypto-2.6:
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
```

Usually, there's a long list of files here. In your case, it's only an `.egg`. Which means that you installed the package as a packed `.egg` (thus most probably, you installed it with `easy_install` rather than `pip`: `pip` always unpacks `.egg`s).

Now,

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg'
```

Means that the `.egg` was already deleted (probably you deleted it by hand, or a previous uninstallation process was interrupted), but installation metadata wasn't. IIRC it's kept in a file or directory named something like `pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg-info`.

So, locate it in `site-packages` and delete it.